# How do I get the value and the ID of a parent of an element and reuse it to create another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event listener on input fields that currently create checkboxes based on the value of those inputs, like so:

```
let firstNames = $("input").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
});

$('.copyBoxes').remove();
checkboxInsert.before("<div class='copyBoxes'><p>Which registrant does this ticket belong to?</p></div>");
$(firstNames).each(function(index, fName){
        $('.copyBoxes').append($('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: fName, value: fName, class: 'copyBox', style: 'display:inline;' }));
        $('.copyBoxes').append($('<label />', { 'for': fName, text: fName, class: 'copyBox', style: 'display:inline;' }));
    });
```

What I need to do is also pull the ID of the parent of the input fields and add that as an attribute to the new checkbox.

Comment: `$(this).parent()` returns the parent of the element, and `$(this).parent().attr('id')` is its ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.parent()` to get the parent of an element.

```
$('.copyBoxes').html('<p>Which registrant does this ticket belong to?</p>');
$("input").each(function() {
    var fName = $(this).val();
    var parentID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $('.copyBoxes').append($('<input />', { 
        type: 'checkbox', 
        id: fName, 
        value: fName, 
        'class': 'copyBox', 
        style: 'display:inline;', 
        data: { parent: parentID } 
    })).append($('<label />', { 
        'for': fName, 
        text: fName, 
        'class': 'copyBox', 
        style: 'display:inline;' 
    }));
});
```

BTW, you should quote `class` when using it as an object property, because it's a reserved word in some Javascript implementations (IE).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That works. I was just overthinking it I guess.